# Keeping a div absolute but also in its parent

Tags: html, css, transition

I have a small link with a thumbnail and an excerpt, using css transitions I want the thumbnail to fade out on hover and the excerpt to appear. I'm using % in oppose to pixels as I want my website responsive, however when I add this to my site the excerpt is spread out the width of the page as it has absolute positioning, below is a jfiddle, could anyone help me?

```
.col {
    width:29%; 
    margin:0 auto;
}
.post-thumbnail {
    position:relative;  
    float:left; 
    overflow:auto; 
    width:100%; height:278px; 
    background:#2F3B45;
}
    .post-thumbnail img {
    width:100%; height:223px; 
    padding:0; margin:0;
    transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.col:hover .post-thumbnail img {
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=00);
}
.post-excerpt {
    width:100%;
    z-index:9999;
    opacity:1; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=1);
}
.post-excerpt p {
    text-align:justify;
    color:#a3aaac;
    font-family:'Open Sans', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:9pt; font-weight:200;      
    line-height:18pt;
    text-decoration:none; width:100%;
}
.col:hover .post-excerpt {
    opacity:1; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=1);
}
.post-title {
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0px; left:0px; 
    width:100%; height:55px; 
    background:#ff0000; z-index:9999;
    text-align:center; line-height:52px;
}
.post-title a {
    font-family:'Open Sans', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:10pt; font-weight:200;  
    color:#000; text-decoration:none;
}
.post-more {
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0px; left:0px; 
    width:100%; height:0px; 
    background:#ff0000;
    opacity:0.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=00);
}
.col:hover .post-title {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0px; left:0px; 
    width:100%; height:95px; 
    background:#ff0000; line-height:44px;
}
.col:hover .post-more {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0px; left:0px; 
    width:100%; height:47px; 
    background:#fff url(http://liamhodnett.com/img/new/read-entry.png)top left no-repeat;  
    z-index:99999;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P3k9A/

Thanks guys!

Comment: What's the problem? What spreads out into what, when?

Comment: "HTML and CSS are both by far the most abundant computer languages around, or at least for creating web pages, at least for now. However when I look back five or six years ago when." Um… wat? HTML and CSS aren't languages. And that's a run on sentence… And the last sentence is ended with a period even tho it's not complete.

Comment: I can't really tell exactly what you are trying to do in your fiddle. But usually all you have to do is set the parent's position to relative.

Comment: Yes.. please I need more clarification to be able to help..

Comment: Do you need the positioning to be absolute?  I often find that position: absolute is not needed, and it often causes difficulties in development.  I avoid it like the frame tag.

Comment: Hi @bjb568 the excerpt is placed on top of the thumbnail and has a 0 opacity, when hover is initiated the the excerpt is to become visible and the thumbnail takes one the 0 opacity, in effect they just swap. however because the excerpt is 'on top' of the thumbnail it requires absolute positioning there for removing it from the parent which makes it spread 100% width of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the parent to relative, then set the children to absolute.

Here are the ones I changed:

```
.col {
    width:29%; 
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative; /* <- here */
}
.post-thumbnail {
    position:absolute;  /* <- here */ 
    top: 0px;
    float:left; 
    overflow:auto; 
    width:100%; height:278px; 
    background:#2F3B45;
}
.post-excerpt {
    position: absolute; /* <- here */
    width:100%;
    z-index:9999;
    opacity:0; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

I believe this is what you were after: http://jsfiddle.net/P3k9A/1/

(I also changed the opacity to 0 on the excerpt in the fiddle).

Comment: that works fantastic @McAden HOWEVER as I am using percent widths for my website all elements with absolute are being pulled up out of the parents and spreading the width of the page. Does that make sense or would you prefer me show you ??

Comment: Supply a fiddle and I'll take a look

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JQd39/5/ there you go :) as you can see .col has only 10% width, IF the excerpt and thumbnail were relative they could be 100% of that 10% width, but because because they are set as absolute they are breaking out of there parent and spreading the width of the page. @McAden

Comment: You didn't apply my solution - add `position: relative` to `.col`

Comment: oops! its been a long day ;) thanks @McAden! Works like a charm